# CSS properties for a child selector in CSS

Tags: html, css, selector, text-align

I don't think I fully understand parent child relationships with CSS. For the following html, I have the following CSS properties set like so:

```
#formContainer{
    text-align: center;
}

.announcement{
    text-align: right;
}
```

However, all the text within `#formContainer`, including `.announcement`, is aligned to the center. How do I properly set the CSS so that the text in `.announcement` is to aligned to the right?

```
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div id="mainBody">
            <div id="formContainer">
                <div class="announcement">
                    <p>Announcement</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input id="email" type="email" name="email">
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit">
                </div>
                <div class="announcement">
                    <p>Register for our mailing list!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: text-align: right !important; will work anyway

Comment: #formContainer .announcement{
    text-align: right;
}

Comment: I think whatever you have in flex-container is messing it up.  What you posted seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the CSS is doing exactly what you are telling it to do.

You have got two `.announcement` class divs inside your `#formContainer`.  And in your css you do this:

```
.announcement{
    text-align: right;
}
```

This means that every div in your html with the class announcement is going to have its text right-aligned.

If you wanted to target only the `.announcement` inside of your `#formContainer`, you could do this:

```
#formContainer .announcement{
    text-align: right;
}
```

That means that you are only targeting the class `.announcement` that are inside the `#formContainer` div.  No other `.announcement` class in you HTML will get this class, except if it is inside a div with id `#formContainer`.

If you only wanted to target the direct child, or first `.announcement` class inside your `#formContainer` div, you could do this:

```
#formContainer > .announcement{
    text-align: right;
}
```

This now means that you are only targeting the direct, or first, child with class `.announcement` that comes directly after div with id `#formContainer`.  No other div, inside or outside of `#formContainer` with class `.announcement` is going to get targeted.

Make sense?

Comment: "Make sense?" Course it does. But how is any of that relevant? The point is that the asker isn't seeing the expected behavior - which you've addressed in your leading statement at least.

Comment: @BoltClock yes indeed, but they also said that they might not fully understand parent-child relationships, so I also tried to address that.

Comment: OK, fair enough.